# Nginx proxy_pass CORS Issue

Tags: nginx, cors, cross-domain, proxypass

I have a simple nginx config but there is a problem with CORS
this is my nginx configuration which will proxy_pass requests to the API application.

```
location /myapp/result{
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8084/myapp/result;
}
```

When I'm doing a post from postman it's working fine but over another website gives a CORS error, this is the exact message:

> Invalid CORS request

Thanks to all

Comment: have you added any headers in your nginx configuration?

Comment: Actually I have added such this add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' but it's same

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think your CORS problem is coming from your API application and not your nginx.

- You can add this to transfer the host to your API application:

  `proxy_set_header  Host  $host;`

  Then, you can check it directly in the API Application.
- Or, simply add an authorization to allow all origins directly in the application.

Also, by default, [`add_header`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_header) is adding the header only to successful responses.

Comment: no unfortunately it's not working. I've checked the application there is no problem with it.